# SQL get differences in one column by ID

Tags: sql

It's hard for me to word what I want which is why I've had trouble researching this issue.  What I want is to look at a table by id and see if another column changes:

```
 id     name
----   ------
 1      Al
 2      Mia
 1      Al
 2      Jean
```

In the example, I don't care about `id 1` because the name always stayed as `Al` but I care about `id 2` because there is a record with the name `Mia` but then, that `id 2` also has a record with the name `Jean`.  I was thinking of using `group by` somehow but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the database you are actually using.

Comment: `id` is a bad example. A column called ID in a table should uniquely identify one record in that table. But anyway, if you are concerned about *different* names for an ID in the table, but not about *duplicate* names for an ID, then this suggests a bad database design where you store redundant data. You may want to change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id  
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(name) <> MAX(name)
```

This will select all ids having *at least two* different values.